# How do I fly using Elytra?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So the new item, Elytra on 1.9 are supposed to make you glide. I have used them at my friend's house when we were playing snapshots but when the update came out, I tried them at my house and all that happened was I fell to my death. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my Elytra Wings are not activating?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260210/why-are-my-elytra-wings-are-not-activating)

Comment: @pppery This older question and its answers are more highly upvoted than the proposed dupe's, suggesting to me that this question and its answers are of higher quality. Shouldn't the dupe closure be the other way around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fly with the elytra, you first have to jump again while falling. Once you do, the elytra will be activated, and then you angle your mouse towards where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how i  forgot to jump while falling.

Comment: No problem :) Have fun! Me and my friends have been playing in 1.9 too and the Elytra is so much fun.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be sure:

- Did you try holding space while falling down?
- Does it work in singleplayer? (If it does, then there must be something wrong with the server)
- You probably need to fall down from higher distances.

Answer (score 3):

When in midair, you have to press `Jump` again to glide. (default <kbd>Space</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

In the official release of Minecraft 1.9, you must be careful how do you land, unlike 1.9 snapshots. **You must now be careful not to land to roughly, *like landing right on your head*, now you must glide close to the ground level and land smoothly.**