# Why are my Elytra Wings are not activating?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Why do my Elytra Wings only work intermittently?

I do not forget to jump, but when I switch to Survival and then back to Creative, they won't activate whatsoever. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are your controls? Are you using any mods?

Comment: There are quite a few bugs with the Elytra at the moment, and as such there is no literal fix for it. I would suggest looking at the issue tracker for Elytra to see progress on current bugs: https://goo.gl/DX9GX5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fly using Elytra?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257395/how-do-i-fly-using-elytra)

Comment: Could be a duplicate, but it is unclear what the OP means with "I do not forget to jump". As such, I propose to close it as unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

To fly the Elytra you need to press the space key in mid-air. If you don't do this you will fall like normal. Even when you jump off the block you need to jump one more time in the air.
[image: How To Fly Steps]

Answer (score 0):

I found that, when I used a slime block for launching, I had the switch low to the ground. That meant that I was looking down when I launched, and flew straight into the ground while trying to work out why the wings weren't working.

I have now moved the switch to head height, two blocks in front of the launcher ensuring I am facing forward when I launch, and I glide off the platform.