# How do use elytra wings in minecraft java edition. I’m in1.14.30

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I’m in survival I double click jump like the way you fly in creative mode. But I just stay on the ground. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fly using Elytra?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257395/how-do-i-fly-using-elytra)

Answer (score 2):

With Elytra wings, you can glide down from higher altitudes by pressing space mid-air. You can propell yourself, and even take off from the ground, by the use of fireworks.

[Here's a more detailed guide](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_use_elytra.php)